# bcp command inserts 0 rows copied

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm a bcp newbie and I want to insert a large file. After bunch of errors I made the following toy example, that I'm trying to use in order to build a baseline that I can build on.

Table SQL:

```
"Create Table dbo.my_test ( " + \
        "transaction_id BIGINT ," + \
        "transaction_no INT ," + \
        "store_no INT ," + \
        ");"
```

my csv file

```
771666690,346138,400
```

my format file:

```
13.0
3
1       SQLBIGINT           1       8       ","   1     transaction_id                                                       ""
2       SQLINT              1       4       ","   2     transaction_no                                                       ""
3       SQLINT              1       4       "\r\n"   3     store_no                                                             ""
```

my bcp command:

```
>bcp data_base.dbo.my_test in "test.csv" -f "test.fmt" -S localhost -U *** -P *****
```

command line output:

```
Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
```

Not sure what to do?

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but the column of all 1s is the prefix length. Shouldn't that be 0s?